# Music player with SMB capabilities and WinAMP playlist support

Tags: android, music, smb

I have an old Motorola Milestone (Droid) that I want to use as a music player. The music files are stored on my Windows PC.

Can anyone suggest me a music player that can access files from a PC using a SMB connection?. I'm using and old CyanogenMod 7 custom ROM (Android 2.3 Gingerbread).

I already try Poweramp and there is no SMB support.

I try Kodi, old versions and new ones, it install but it never start.

I also try subsonic but it need a service to be installed on the PC, and what I want is something independent from source.

I did try Neutron, it starts, I config the source but I can "see" all the folders on the PC HDD, so it doesn't work (or I didn't know how make it work properly).

Samba Network Music Player work PERFECT... but it lacks the WinAMP playlist support. It can't see them nor play them...

Comment: I had similar problem but I solved it in a different way. I just installed very simple streaming server on my Windows PC and used player that supported it. For my case it was VLC on Android.